# subqueries: select from one table based on matching user ids with team ids and output 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select from `login_users` to get the following fields: `name`, `username`, and `user_id`.

I have a separate table `teams` with the team_id, as well as the associated `user_id`, so for example I might have bob with team1, jack with team2, jim with team1, and paul with team2 (all separate rows, not bob and paul -> team2).
If I provide a function with the team_ id I want to be able to find all the associated `user_id`s, and then match that data with `login_users`  to output a two dimensional array that has `name`, `username`, and `user_id` of all the team members.

`SELECT username, user_id, name FROM login_users WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT user_id FROM teams WHERE team_id= $team_id );`

I know it has something to do with sub queries I just have never done them before, and I feel that I am on the wrong track. Furthermore, how would I then go about producing a two dimensional array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with an "exists" subquery, then it needs to be a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT username, user_id, name
FROM login_users
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT user_id
              FROM teams
              WHERE team_id = $team_id and
                    teams.user_id = login_users.team_id
             );
```

You are missing the condition on the `user_id`.  That version of the query is saying "get me all rows from `login_users` when `team_id` exists in `teams`".

Comment: Yea I knew I was missing an integral part. Is this the most efficient way of doing this? It sounds like you were dubious as to whether this was a good way of doing things in this context. Or perhaps I'm just reading too much btwn the lines.

Comment: @Alex . . . This answer was to show you how to modify your query to get the right example.  Typically, given the choice between a `join` and an `exists` clause, I would normally (but not always) choose the `join`.  With an index on `teams(team_id, user_id)`, the performance should be similar (the `exists` could have a slight edge).

Answer (score 2):

Why only subquery ?? why not `JOIN`

```
SELECT u.username, u.user_id, u.`name` FROM login_users u
JOIN teams t ON(u.user_id = t.user_id)
WHERE team_id= $team_id
```